# How do I Make facebook Multiple Score-Elements for every level?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

Facebook has the basic function of one score per person.
I just don't get the hang of it to make multiple score-elements.

I'm trying to make a score-element for every level.
I heard that you should use the **Open Graph** in Facebook but what I mostly find is the use requesting items to your personal Facebook page.

So my Question is:
How do I make multiple scores elements per level that Facebook will save for me

I'm using Facebook with unity C#

Comment: You can only publish one general score value per user for your whole game app, it doesn’t provide the ability to divide that into multiple levels. You might want to look into [Achievements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements) instead; or define your own Open Graph stories that tell people about what players did in your game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get one score...unfortunately.

You would have to use an alternate data save system like Amazon's Cognito
http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/ or something similar.

Ryan